How to add session keys for the collators set as invulnerables are in the nodes?
I am running collators node and I want to add session keys for the collators set as invulnerables in the node. I am using rpc author.insertKey but I am getting RPC call is unsafe to be called externally issue,

How to add session keys in the node?

Add these flags to your node. Remember to remove the flags after the setup if your node is running in the public network.
--rpc-methods unsafe and --unsafe-rpc-external.
